# Angular routing is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I know there are a lot of questions about the routing not working in AngularJS. I have the same problem and after going through hundreds of answers I decided to post this question yet again. I have three files which are in the root folder in c:\intepub\wwwroot\angular\ and this means I am testing it under IIS. Now my problem is that when I put this URL in the browser: `http://localhost/angular/index.html`, browser redirects it to: `http://localhost/angular/index.html#/` and the text on the page is:  Testing routes

However, according to the code, it should go to login.html. And when I put `http://localhost/angular/index.html#/test` it still shows the same text: Testing routes.

Any ideas?

Thanks

The code is shown below:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        Testing routes
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <script src="dep/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="dep/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(appRouter);

        function appRouter($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
        {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                    {
                        templateURL: 'login.html'
                    })
                .when('/test',
                    {
                        templateURL: 'test.html'
                    })
                .otherwise({tempate: "otherwise"});
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<div>
    Login Page
</div>
```

**test.html**

```
<div>
    Test page
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `templateUrl` instead of `templateURL`

Here are properties for $routeProvider:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)

Here is simply tutorial how to use it:
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have missed controller

```
function appRouter($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
        {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                    {
                        templateURL: 'login.html',controller: 'loginCtrl'
                    })
                .when('/test',
                    {
                        templateURL: 'test.html',controller: 'testCtrl'
                    })
                .otherwise({tempate: "otherwise"});
        }
```

**login.html**

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    Login Page
</div>
```

**Test.html**

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    Test Page
</div>
```

Must set the Set as start up page ti index page

[image]

> Right Click the index.html page in Solution explorer> Click the set as start page option in shown popup.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, same problem.

Comment: Please set a set as start page in index page, then try it

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit. I didn't get it.

Comment: What the page for your default page?

Comment: Updated my answer, Pleasee see it mow

Comment: index.html. By the way, shouldn't it work without controllers in partials?

Comment: I am not using Visual Studio. It is plain html and javascript so it should not matter.

Comment: Yes, You must specify the controller, You know the angularjs depend on MVC Framework. So it's should be needed

Comment: hmm ! There have a problem, The index page look like a master page, So you must run the index page first. because the configurations are loaded first.

Comment: As I said, I am not using Visual Studio, its a plain text editor and I don't have web.config. And there is no master page as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the way you've defined your markup:

```
   <div>
        Testing routes
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
```

it will always show "Testing routes" as NG puts view content inside `<div ng-view="">` element. You should change it to something suitable.

Comment: Even by removing the text it doesn't work. The new markup looks like this: <div><div ng-view=""></div></div>